# using current_user variable in python dictionary?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to use a data from pub column in database using `new_variable = current_user.pub` in dictionary but i am getting this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pub'` any help regarding this is much appreciated

here is my full code `

```
pins = {
       4 : {'name' : 'Channel 1', 'board' : 'esp8266', 'topic' : '/4', 'state' : 'False'},
       5 : {'name' : 'Channel 2', 'board' : 'esp8266', 'topic' : '/5', 'state' : 'False'}
       }

    variable = pins[4]['topic']
    new_variable = current_user.pub
    pins[4]['topic'] = new_variable
```

thank you

Comment: where do you define `current_user` ?

Comment: since `current_user` is undefined it is `NoneType` which has no attribute `pub`, create `current_user` to use it

Comment: hey thanks for reply 
actually `current_user` is imported from flask login which is used to call data from pub column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use python @property decorator to create a method in your class. And return the pub whatever you want.

```
class User(db.Models):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    key = db.Column(db.String(80))

    @property
    def pub(self):
        return "{}".format(self.key)
```

Comment: thanks for answer tried  this but i got this error 
`TypeError: object of type 'property' has no len()`

Comment: What you are trying to do? Obviously `pub` not return `list`.

Comment: thats what i did


`pins = {
   4 : {'name' : 'Channel 1', 'board' : 'esp8266', 'topic' : '/4', 'state' : 'False'},
   5 : {'name' : 'Channel 2', 'board' : 'esp8266', 'topic' : '/5', 'state' : 'False'}
   }

@property
def pub(self):
  return "{}".format(self.key)

variable = pins[4]['topic']
pub="{current_user.pub }"
pins[4]['topic'] = pub`

Comment: Are you sure `current_user.pub` return what you expect?

Comment: with `current_user.pub` i am expecting some string in db i already used `pub=current_user.pub` to  show data on template using flask

Comment: The code looks fine to me. My only question is the pub return the value correct or not.

Comment: yes the `pub` can return the values as given input but i want to use `current_user.pub` for pullin data from db